# How to bind a Dictionary<enum,bool> property to a GridViewColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listview

I am trying to bind a Dictionary property stored in a `EffectViewModel` inside an `ObservableCollection`, but it appears as "(Collection)" in the column I want to see as checkboxes.

Xaml for the `GridViewColumn` is this:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="100"
    Header="GPU"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShaderSupport}">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

`ShaderSupport` is of type `Dictionary<ShaderType, bool>` where I just want to read in the bool value for ShaderType.GPU for this GridViewColumn.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Using this shows me the bool value as string, so I am in the right path I think:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShaderSupport[GPU]}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="100"
    Header="GPU">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding ShaderSupport[CPU]}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, this works great. If I wanted this to be 2-way, would it work by just using Mode=TwoWay?

Comment: @Joan - I haven't tried but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.